# Bash on Windows doesn't seem to run just an underscore blinking

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I followed instruction enabling bash on ubunutu on Windows 10 and it run ok first time. After pressing Windows button typing `bash` and runnning it I only get a console window with an `_`blinking:

[image]

Anyone knows what to do next

Comment: I assume you have enabled developer mode, enabled the required Windows feature, and have fixed your inability to elevate processes permissions because you don't have an enabled Administrator account.  If this is a computer connected to an Active Domain it also is possible that has something to do with Bash not working.

Comment: @Ramhound I decided to reset windows as following your instructions didn't help me create or elevate the admin user

Comment: Of course it didn't.  The built-in Administrator account is disabled by default.  You still have to enable it.